# Help with matlab and fourier series

Tags: matlab

This is the fourier series I've calculated using wolfram alpha

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(i*0.5)/(2*pi*-2)*e^(i*-4*pi*x/0.5)%2B(i*0.5)/(-2*pi)*e^(-i*2*pi*x/0.5)%2B(0.5/2)*1%2B(i*0.5)/(2*pi)*e^(i*2*pi*x/0.5)%2B(i*0.5)/(4*pi)*e^(i*4*pi*x/0.5)
```

This is how I write in matlab for eg C(-2)

```
(0.5*i/2*pi*-2)*exp(1).^(i*2*-2*pi*x/0.5)+....
```

But the plot is not at all close to the original, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As a followup from Ben's point, always use `1i` instead of `i`, because it will withstand the use of `i` as a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

You have not parenthesized the expression the same (eg consider `/(2*pi*-2)` vs `/2*pi*-2`).  It's also possible you used `i` as an index variable in your workspace and it is no longer the complex value `sqrt(-1)`.